# How can I insert master/detail records into SQL server using parameterized stored procedure with XML detail records as one of the params

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I want to create a C# method that calls a parameterized SQL Server stored procedure. The parameters I am passing are;

```
*int ServiceActionType 
*string FilePath
*string ServiceName
*string ApplicationServerName
*XmlDocument ListOfPieceIDs
```

In the stored procedure, I first want to create the master record, in the ServiceActions table, consisting of the ServiceActionType, FilePath, ServiceName, ApplicationServerName, PieceCount (which would be the count of the elements in the XML document) and the ActionDateTime (the current date and time)

I want to save the master record and get it's Identity value to use in the next step.

Then I want to iterate through the XML document and insert new records in the ServiceActionsPieceIDs table, one record for each XML element, with each record having the following fields;

```
*ServiceActionID (the Identity value from the newly inserted ServiceActions record)
*PieceID (The PieceID value from the current iteration through the XML document)
```

I believe I have the C# method created properly but I am having trouble figuring out the T-SQL stored procedure code to insert the ServiceAction master record, get the Identity field from the ServiceAction master record insert and then iterate through the XML document to extract the PieceID element value from each element set to insert the ServiceActionPieceIDs detail records.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Does your Master data have a unique natural key value?

Comment: Yes, an identity field, called ID, is included in the ServiceActions table.